# How can I fix Blank arrays on Ruby on Rails views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to display some information in my views, but it doesn't return any information and it appears completely blank in the view

that's my controller:

```
  class Spree::Admin::StocklogController < Spree::Admin::BaseController
      before_action :load_movements
      def index
      end
      def load_movements
        @stockmovelog = Spree::StockMovement.all
      end
    end
```

And that's my view:

```
<% @stockmovelog.each do |movement| %>
      <tr>
        <td><% movement.id %></td>
        <td class="align-center"><% movement.quantity %></td>
        <td><% movement.created_at %></td>
        <td class="align-right"><% movement.updated_at %></td>
        <td class="actions"><% movement.action %></td>
      </tr>
<% end %>
```

It will simply create the number of rows from `each` and keep the content blank, there is something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that `Spree::StockMovement.all` is not empty ?

Comment: It is not! It does return every single array in my console, it's 30 entries in total, the view creates 30 rows but the content inside of `<% @stockmovelog.each do |movement| %>`, it won't display the id in `<% movement.id %>` for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `=` to the ERB inside the `td`'s:

```rb
<% @stockmovelog.each do |movement| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= movement.id %></td>
    <td class="align-center"><%= movement.quantity %></td>
    <td><%= movement.created_at %></td>
    <td class="align-right"><%= movement.updated_at %></td>
    <td class="actions"><%= movement.action %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```